# In AWS, should Route53 be configured to route requests to a Load Balancer or an API gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, load-balancing, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

Consider a scenario where I have an application deployed on EC2 instances. This application uses an API Gateway for authentication/authorization, defining schema and validating the inputs, caching etc.
Also for scalability and High availability, I have a multi-AZ setup where I use a load balancer to balance incoming requests amongst the EC2 instances.

Now, does the API Gateway sit in front of the Load balancer or does the Load balancer sit in front of the API gateway? As per that should I register an API gateway endpoint or a load balancer endpoint with Route 53 public hosted zone?

Comment: The API Gateway sits in front of the load balancer as otherwise, the load balancer isn't really 'balancing' anything with 1 API gateway.